# Automatically get APN

Tags: networking

It seems that my phone somehow can get APN settings automatically, after inserting my old SIM card to the new phone `m.tinkoff` in iOS Mobile Data Network menu appeared automatically, and this correct one for my mobile operator. However, when I’m trying to config some LTE modem to connect to the Internet, I have to config APN settings manually.

How did my phone get correct settings? Is it some database with settings for all mobile operators all over the world supported by Apple, or there is some standard protocol to fetch default after registration in operator network?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I fail to see the link with IoT in this question, hence it is almost certainly off-topic on this site; please take the [tour] to earn your first badge and visit the [help] center for more information about how to ask a good question for this site.  If you feel like learning even more, you can browse the [site scope section on meta](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-scope). Thanks!

Comment: From the ICCID, the phone can know the carrier. For some carriers, I think Apple also has an APN. Not for all. They still will allow you to change the APN if the "use carrier settings" doesnt work. I dont know if the carrier can push down a change in APN when they send down other things that customize the phone (and lock/unlock the phone).